# Set schema name for specific table mappings using JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa

We are using JPA (hibernate) and have certain tables in a specific schema. I know schema names can be set in the ORM mapping file for a given persistence unit but we have a need to set the schema name for only certain object mappings. So the question is: is there a way in JPA to set the schema name for specific object mappings and not for all object mappings, using a single persistence unit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To map an entity with the table & some specific schema, you can use attributes `name` & `schema` of the table annotaion.

```
@Entity
    @Table(name="PERSON", schema="RECORDS")
    public class Person { ... }
```